# How to enable SQL on SchemaRDD via the JDBC interface? (is it even possible ?)

Tags: hive, apache-spark, scala-2.10, apache-spark-sql

*UPDATING the problem statement*

We are using spark 1.2.0 (Hadoop 2.4). We have defined SchemaRDDs using data files in HDFS and would like to enable querying these as tables via HiveServer2. We are encountering runtime exceptions while trying to saveAsTable and would like guidance on how to proceed.

Source code:

```
package foo.bar

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._

object HiveDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Demo")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // sc is an existing SparkContext.
    val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

    // Create an RDD
    val zipRDD = sc.textFile("/model-inputs/all_zip_state.csv")

    // The schema is encoded in a string
    val schemaString = "ODSMEMBERID,ZIPCODE,STATE,TEST_SUPPLIERID,ratio_death_readm_low,ratio_death_readm_high,regions"

    // Generate the schema based on the string of schema
    val schema =
      StructType(
        schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

    // Convert records of the RDD (zip) to Rows.
    val rowRDD = zipRDD.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), ""))

    // Apply the schema to the RDD.
    val zipSchemaRDD = hiveContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)

    // HiveContext's save as Table
    zipSchemaRDD.saveAsTable("allzipstable")

  }
}
```

spark-submit Command:

```
./bin/spark-submit  --class foo.bar.HiveDemo --master yarn-cluster --jars /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-metastore.jar,/usr/lib/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/lib/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/usr/lib/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 1 lib/datapipe_2.10-1.0.jar 10
```

Exception at runtime on Node:

```
15/01/29 22:35:50 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: Unresolved plan found, tree:
'CreateTableAsSelect None, allzipstable, false, None
 LogicalRDD [ODSMEMBERID#0,ZIPCODE#1,STATE#2,TEST_SUPPLIERID#3,ratio_death_readm_low#4,ratio_death_readm_high#5,regions#6], MappedRDD[3] at map at HiveDemo.scala:30
)
Exception in thread "Driver" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Unresolved plan found, tree:
'CreateTableAsSelect None, allzipstable, false, None
 LogicalRDD [ODSMEMBERID#0,ZIPCODE#1,STATE#2,TEST_SUPPLIERID#3,ratio_death_readm_low#4,ratio_death_readm_high#5,regions#6], MappedRDD[3] at map at HiveDemo.scala:30

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$.apply(Analyzer.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$.apply(Analyzer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.withCachedData(SQLContext.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(SQLContext.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.saveAsTable(SchemaRDDLike.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.saveAsTable(SchemaRDD.scala:108)
    at com.healthagen.datapipe.ahm.HiveDemo$.main(HiveDemo.scala:36)
    at com.healthagen.datapipe.ahm.HiveDemo.main(HiveDemo.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:427)
15/01/29 22:35:50 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Invoking sc stop from shutdown hook
```

Another attempt:

```
package foo.bar

import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.sql._

case class AllZips(
  ODSMEMBERID: String,
  ZIPCODE: String,
  STATE: String,
  TEST_SUPPLIERID: String,
  ratio_death_readm_low: String,
  ratio_death_readm_high: String,
  regions: String)

object HiveDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveDemo")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    import hiveContext._
    val allZips = sc.textFile("/model-inputs/all_zip_state.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => AllZips(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), ""))
    val allZipsSchemaRDD = createSchemaRDD(allZips)
    allZipsSchemaRDD.saveAsTable("allzipstable")
  }
}
```

Exception on node:

```
15/01/30 00:28:19 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: Unresolved plan found, tree:
'CreateTableAsSelect None, allzipstable, false, None
 LogicalRDD [ODSMEMBERID#0,ZIPCODE#1,STATE#2,TEST_SUPPLIERID#3,ratio_death_readm_low#4,ratio_death_readm_high#5,regions#6], MapPartitionsRDD[4] at mapPartitions at ExistingRDD.scala:36
)
Exception in thread "Driver" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Unresolved plan found, tree:
'CreateTableAsSelect None, allzipstable, false, None
 LogicalRDD [ODSMEMBERID#0,ZIPCODE#1,STATE#2,TEST_SUPPLIERID#3,ratio_death_readm_low#4,ratio_death_readm_high#5,regions#6], MapPartitionsRDD[4] at mapPartitions at ExistingRDD.scala:36

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$.apply(Analyzer.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$CheckResolution$.apply(Analyzer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.withCachedData(SQLContext.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(SQLContext.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.saveAsTable(SchemaRDDLike.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.saveAsTable(SchemaRDD.scala:108)
    at com.healthagen.datapipe.ahm.HiveDemo$.main(HiveDemo.scala:22)
    at com.healthagen.datapipe.ahm.HiveDemo.main(HiveDemo.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:427)
15/01/30 00:28:19 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Invoking sc stop from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createSchemaRDD code snippet from above works fine on spark 1.2.1

There was a CTAS defect in 1.2.0

Comment: what is a CTAS defect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a ***HiveContext***

Here are the java/scala docs:

```
   * Note that this currently only works with SchemaRDDs that are created from a HiveContext as
   * there is no notion of a persisted catalog in a standard SQL context. 


  @Experimental
  def saveAsTable(tableName: String): Unit =
    sqlContext.executePlan(CreateTableAsSelect(None, tableName, logicalPlan, false)).toRdd
```

So in your code change it to:

```
val sc = new HiveContext(conf)
```

Actually you should rename it to

```
val sqlc = new HiveContext(conf)
```

FYI: more info about registering tables (in SQLContext): note the tables are transient if done this way:

```
  /**
   *  Temporary tables exist only
   * during the lifetime of this instance of SQLContext.
   *
   * @group userf
   */
  def registerRDDAsTable(rdd: SchemaRDD, tableName: String): Unit = {
    catalog.registerTable(Seq(tableName), rdd.queryExecution.logical)
  }
```

**UPDATE**  Your new stacktrace includes the following phrase:

```
Unresolved plan found, tree:
```

That typically means you have a column that does not match the underlying table.  I will look further to see if am able to isolate - but in the meantime you might also consider from that perspective.

Comment: If you are not ready to award answer yet, please consider to upvote this answer as having been helpful.

Comment: absolutely ! you have any ideas for the runtime exception on nodes ?

Comment: added to my answer about checking the column names.

Comment: @DebajyotiRoy where is the code for createSchemaRdd()? not shown in your snippet.

Comment: i have two flavors of code, one using applySchema and other using createSchema. Both don't work got a response from user-list that it was fixed on 1.2.1-snapshot. haven't tried that yet